# How to change default directory of a setup launcher exe?

Tags: installation

I have a setup file for a particular application. When I run this file it automatically creates a folder in my C/: drive without consulting me and installs some stuff in there. Then it installs the rest of the stuff in Programfilesx86 folder in C/: drive. It is really frustrating that I have no control in deciding these parameters.

I managed to open the setup file using Winrar and there were six folders in there numbered from 'disk 1' to 'disk 6'. In 'disk 1' there are a couple of setup files which when run skip the first part of the setup (in which a folder is created in the C/: drive) and starts installing stuff in Programfilesx86.

There are also some other stuff in that folder which I tried to open with Notepad such as setup.lid, setup.ins and dll and bin files. Some of them looked sensible when opened, but some contained a lot of funny looking and meaningless characters (at least to me).

If you want something for testing (i.e. the software of interest), try downloading the Motec ECU manager from their website for free.

Any help or hints are appreciated.

Comment: Are you using visual studio setup project for creating installer/msi?

Comment: No. I know what visual studio is, but I have never used it for creating installer/msi. Do I need to use that if I want to modify the default installation directory? Is there no way of modifying the files in the 'disk 1' folder and make that happen? By the way you can install the ECU manager software to exactly see what I am talking about.

Comment: misunderstood your question due to tags "Setup-deployment", "setup-project". Your question is not related to development at all instead, you are asking for a third party installer that how to choose installation directory.

Comment: Sorry about that. I edited the question and removed those tags.